# print variable with alignment

Tags: php

I manually execute a query and copy paste the output to an editor.Now it is well aligned like:

> Hi,
>
> This is sample data.
>
> Thanks.

If I stored the output of the query in a php varibale and print it using echo command it is not aligned. It looks like

> Hi, This is sample data. Thanks.

Is it possible to print the output as it is in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need `<pre>` tag for that. but I suggest you should format it with proper html

```
echo "<pre>".$youvariable."</pre>";
```

Comment: like  echo nl2br($text); or echo '<pre>.$text.'</pre>';

Answer (score 0):

PHP prints it perfectly fine. If you're looking at it in a browser though, **consecutive spaces and newlines are collapsed into a single space** by the browser. Replace newlines with `<br>` tags to keep them, using [`nl2br`](http://php.net/nl2br).